# Cuando hago click en uno de los cards de un recyclerview para marcarlo, cada 10 cards se vuelve a marcar otro, es decir, cada 10 cards se marca 1

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragment, recyclerview

Buenos Días/Tardes/Noches, tengo un problemilla cuando hago click sobre un card cualquiera de mi recycler view.

Tengo un fragment con un recyclerview que muestra una lista de canciones, y cuando hago click sobre un card para marcarlo cambiando el color de los TextView que contiene, se vuelve a repetir el marcado en los cards inferiores. Pero lo curioso es que se marcan cada 10 cards, es decir, cada 10 cards se marca un card. Espero que me haya explicado bien...

Gracias por la ayuda, aquí dejo mi codigo...

CustomAdapterSongList->

```
class CustomAdapterSongList(
        val context: Context,
        val lifecycle: LifecycleOwner,
        val layout: Int,
        onSongListener: OnSongListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapterSongList.ViewHolder>() {

    private var ListSongs: List<Song> = emptyList()
    private var onSongListener = onSongListener

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val viewlayout = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(viewlayout, context)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val itemsong = ListSongs[position]
        holder.bind(itemsong, lifecycle, onSongListener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return ListSongs.size
    }

    internal fun setSongs(songs: List<Song>) {
        this.ListSongs = songs
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class ViewHolder(viewlayout: View, val context: Context) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewlayout), View.OnClickListener {

        private lateinit var onSongListener:OnSongListener

        fun bind(dataitem: Song, lifecycle: LifecycleOwner, onSongListener: OnSongListener) {
            // itemview es el item de diseño
            // al que hay que poner los datos del objeto dataItem
            itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title_song).text = dataitem.title
            itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.artist_name).text = dataitem.artistName
            this.onSongListener = onSongListener

            var song_artWork = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart")
            song_artWork = ContentUris.withAppendedId(song_artWork, dataitem.id)

            Picasso.get()
                    .load(File(song_artWork.getPath()))
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_standard_image_song)
                    .into(itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_image_song))

            itemView.tag = dataitem
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
            onSongListener.onSongClick(adapterPosition, itemView)
        }
    }

    interface OnSongListener {
        fun onSongClick(position: Int, itemView: View)
    }
}
```

SongListFragment

```
class SongListFragment : Fragment(), SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, View.OnClickListener, CustomAdapterSongList.OnSongListener {

    private lateinit var songsListViewModel: SongListViewModel
    private var song: MutableLiveData<Song> = MutableLiveData<Song>()

    private lateinit var fragmentView: View
    private var songView: CardView? = null

    private lateinit var adapter: CustomAdapterSongList

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_songlist, container, false)
        (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.setSupportActionBar(fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_songFragment))
        setHasOptionsMenu(true) //indicamos a la activity host (MainActivity) que el fragmento tiene items de menu que quiere añadir


        init()

        return fragmentView
    }

    private fun init() {
        setAdapter()

        songsListViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SongListViewModel::class.java)
        songsListViewModel.showAllDeviceSongs(adapter, fragmentView)

/*        //observador -> observa la variable MutableLiveData<List<Song>> de el viewModel, para que cuando cambie actualice la lista
        songsListViewModel.getSongsList().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { it ->
            it?.let {
                songsListViewModel.showAllDeviceSongs()
            }
        })*/
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_song_list, menu)
        val menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search)

        if (menuItem != null) {
            val searchView = menuItem.actionView as SearchView
            searchView.setQueryHint("Search...")
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
        }

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
        val original = songsListViewModel.getListSongs().value
        if (original != null && query != null) {
            adapter.setSongs(original.filter { song -> song.title.toUpperCase().contains(query.toUpperCase()) })
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        val original = songsListViewModel.getListSongs().value
        if (original != null && newText != null) {
            adapter.setSongs(original.filter { song -> song.title.toUpperCase().contains(newText.toUpperCase()) })
        }
        return false
    }


    private fun setAdapter() {
        adapter = activity?.let { CustomAdapterSongList(it.applicationContext, this, R.layout.custom_card_song, this) }!!
        fragmentView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_deviceSongs).layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(fragmentView.context)
        fragmentView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_deviceSongs).adapter = adapter
    }


    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
    }

    override fun onSongClick(position: Int, itemView: View) {
        songView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title_song)?.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(fragmentView.context, R.color.principal_text_color))
        songView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.artist_name)?.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(fragmentView.context, R.color.principal_text_color))

        song.value = songsListViewModel.clickSong(position)

        songView = itemView as CardView
        itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title_song).setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
        itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.artist_name).setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
    }

    fun getClickedSong(): LiveData<Song> {
        return song
    }

}

SongListViewModel
```

class SongListViewModel() : ViewModel() {

```
private var listSongs = MutableLiveData<List<Song>>()

fun showAllDeviceSongs(adapter:CustomAdapterSongList, view: View) {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        getAllDeviceSongs(view)
        listSongs.value?.let { adapter.setSongs(it) }
    }
}

fun getListSongs(): MutableLiveData<List<Song>> {
    return listSongs
}

private fun getAllDeviceSongs(view: View) {
    listSongs.value = LocalSongsProvider.getAllDeviceSongs(view.context)
}

fun clickSong(position:Int): Song? {
    return listSongs.value?.get(position)?.let { it }
}
```

}

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, PlayerControl, View.OnClickListener {

    private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel

    private lateinit var homeFragment: HomeFragment
    private lateinit var songListFragment: SongListFragment
    private lateinit var albumsFragment: AlbumsFragment
    private lateinit var cardView: CardView

    private lateinit var mService: MusicPlayerService
    private var bindState: Boolean = false

    private lateinit var selectedSong: Song

    private val connection = object :
        ServiceConnection { //conexion que se usa para conectarse al servicio de MusicPlayer

        override fun onServiceConnected(className: ComponentName, service: IBinder) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            val binder = service as MusicPlayerService.LocalBinder
            mService = binder.getService()
            bindState = true
        }

        override fun onServiceDisconnected(arg0: ComponentName) {
            bindState = false
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        init()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            val readPermission = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) {}
            readPermission.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        }
    }

    private fun welcomeInit(){

        var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // There are no request codes
                val data: Intent? = result.data
                if (data != null) {
                    if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!=null){
                        this.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_home_welcome).text = "Buenos dias " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.displayName + "..."
                    } else {
                        this.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_home_welcome).text = "Buenos dias..."
                    }                
                }
            }
        }

        resultLauncher.launch(Intent(this, AuthActivity::class.java))
        //this.onPause()
    }

    private fun init() {
        mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        if (!mainViewModel.checkAuth()){
            welcomeInit()
        }

        setNavController()
        initMusicPlayerService()

        songListFragment.getClickedSong().observe(this, Observer { it ->
            it?.let {
                this.selectedSong = it
                showControlMusicCard(true, it)
                playSong(it.contentUri)
            }
        })

        setRandomBackground()
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        lateinit var selectedFragment: Fragment

        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> selectedFragment = homeFragment
            R.id.navigation_songsList -> selectedFragment = songListFragment
            R.id.navigation_albums -> selectedFragment = albumsFragment
        }

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, selectedFragment)
            .commit()

        return true
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.d("Activity", "OnDestroy activity...")

        Intent(this, MusicPlayerService::class.java).also {
            stopService(it)
        }

    }

    private fun setNavController() {
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

        homeFragment = HomeFragment()
        songListFragment = SongListFragment()
        albumsFragment = AlbumsFragment()

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, homeFragment)
            .commit()

    }

    private fun initMusicPlayerService() {
//        Intent(this, MusicPlayerService::class.java).also {
//            startService(it)
//        }

        Intent(this, MusicPlayerService::class.java).also { intent ->
            bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
        }

    }

    private fun showControlMusicCard(state: Boolean, song: Song) {
        cardView = findViewById<CardView>(R.id.cardControl)
        val animation: Animation

        cardView.setOnClickListener(this)
        cardView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.control_artist_name).also {
            it.isSelected = true
            it.text = song.artistName
        }
        cardView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.control_title_song).also {
            it.isSelected = true
            it.text = song.title
        }
        cardView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.ib_play_pause).also {
            it.setOnClickListener(this)
            if (!mService.isPlaying()) {
                it.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_icon)
            }
        }
        cardView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.ib_previous).setOnClickListener(this)
        cardView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.ib_next).setOnClickListener(this)

        if (state) {
            animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_show)
            cardView.isGone = false
            cardView.isVisible = true
            cardView.startAnimation(animation)
        } else {
            animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_hide)
            cardView.isGone = true
            cardView.startAnimation(animation)
        }


    }

    override fun playSong(pathSong: String) {
        mService.playSong(pathSong)
    }

    override fun pauseSong() {
        mService.pauseSong()
    }

    override fun stopSong() {
        mService.stopSong()
    }

    override fun resumeSong() {
        if (!mService.isPlaying()) {
            mService.resumeSong()
            cardView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.ib_play_pause)
                .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_icon)
        } else {
            mService.pauseSong()
            cardView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.ib_play_pause)
                .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_icon)
        }
    }

    override fun nextSong() {
    }

    override fun previusSong() {
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        if (v != null) {
            when (v.id) {
                R.id.ib_play_pause -> resumeSong()
                R.id.ib_next -> nextSong()
                R.id.ib_previous -> previusSong()
                R.id.cardControl -> showSongFragment()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setRandomBackground() {
        val randomNumber = (Math.random() * 5 + 1).toInt()
        Log.d("id", "bg_main_activity_$randomNumber")
        val background: Drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            this,
            resources.getIdentifier("bg_main_activity_$randomNumber", "drawable", this.packageName)
        )!!

        this.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.activity_container).background = background
    }

    private fun showSongFragment() {
        val intent = Intent(this, SongActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("song", selectedSong)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como su nombre lo indica, el recyclerView recicla views. Esto significa que sólo crea las views que son visibles + unas pocas mas para garantizar un scroll suave. En tu caso el resultado es 10. Tu item 11 usa la misma view que el 1 pero los datos cambian porque se ejecuta el método `bind` de tu viewHolder. Entonces lo que debes hacer es setear el background en ese método dependiendo de si el item está seleccionado o no. Por ejemplo así

```
class CustomAdapterSongList(
    private val layoutId: Int,
    private val onSongClickListener: (Song) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapterSongList.ViewHolder>() {

    private var songs: List<Song> = emptyList()
    private var selectedSongs = mutableSetOf<Int>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = ViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layoutId, parent, false)
    )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) = holder.bind(songs[position])

    override fun getItemCount() = songs.size

    fun setSongs(songs: List<Song>) {
        this.songs = songs
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        // esto evita tener que hacer un findViewById en cada bind
        private var titleTxt = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title_song)
        private var artistTxt = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.artist_name)
        private var imageView = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_image_song)

        private fun updateColor() = itemView.setBackgroundColor(
            if (bindingAdapterPosition in selectedSongs) Color.LTGRAY else Color.WHITE
        )

        fun bind(song: Song) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                bindingAdapterPosition.let {
                    if (it in selectedSongs) selectedSongs.remove(it)
                    else selectedSongs.add(it)
                }
                updateColor()
                onSongClickListener(song)
            }
            titleTxt.text = song.title
            artistTxt.text = song.artistName
            val song_artWork = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart"),
                song.id
            )
            Picasso.get()
                .load(File(song_artWork.path!!))
                .error(R.drawable.ic_standard_image_song)
                .into(imageView)
            updateColor()
        }
    }
}
```

Refactoricé todo tu adapter para mostrarte como usar kotlin apropiadamente. Espero que lo apliques al resto de tu código. Sabrás que lo estás haciendo bien cuando tus activities y fragments no necesiten implementar ninguna interfaz. Además estás haciendo un mal uso del liveData y en tu viewModel no debería haber ninguna referencia al adapter, se supone que eso va en el fragment.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, pero si quisiera que cuando seleccione un elemento de la lista se deseleccione el elemento que tenia ya seleccionado anteriormente, como se haría? En mi caso seria, que cuando seleccione una canción para reproducirla, se deseleccione la que estaba reproduciendo anteriormente, no se si me explico...

Comment: he estado investigando y lo único que he encontrado es hacer un notifyDataSetChanged(), pero no logro que funcione

Comment: Bueno ese es un caso diferente. Tendrías que hacer otra pregunta para que pueda explicarlo bien. Pero debes saber que hay una librería llamada `RecyclerView-Selection` que te facilita ese trabajo. Estos son algunos ejemplos [1](https://medium.com/coding-blocks/implementing-selection-in-recyclerview-36a9739844e0) [2](https://proandroiddev.com/a-guide-to-recyclerview-selection-3ed9f2381504)